# Access CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting `./vacancy-data.csv cannot be found` error when trying to pass in the csv into `csvtojson` npm package?

The csv is in the same directory as the following code:

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;

router.get('/search',function(req,res){
  var converter = new Converter({});

  converter.fromFile('./vacancy-data.csv',function(err,result){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried `require('./vacancy-data.csv')`, also tried the `better-require` npm package.

I'm trying to convert the csv to json, then pass the json in the response.

Comment: Are you sure that everything is all right with your security settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it might be because `require` function has its own [resolving strategy](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), which is not applicable to usual nodejs `fs` commands. For example, consider this structure:

```
 -> index.js
 -> routes/
    -> router.js
    -> vacancy-data.csv
```

To resolve `require('./vacancy-data.csv')` in `./routes/router.js`, NodeJS will start looking from current module path, which is `./routes/` in this case.

However, when you run `node index.js` and then make HTTP request, current dir for your web server will be `./` and it will be used to resolve `converter.fromFile('./vacancy-data.csv')`. Try:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter,
    path = require('path');

router.get('/search',function(req,res){
    var converter = new Converter({});

    converter.fromFile(path.join(__dirname, 'vacancy-data.csv'),function(err,result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

`__dirname` is a [global variable](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) which is always set to a dir where currently executed code is located (`<full_path_to_the_project_root>/routes/` in this case).